# Java Spring @ExceptionHandler are not handling errors correctly

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have problem then I try to catch exception.

Here is my class which implements ResponseErrorHandler:

```
    public class ErrorGenerator implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        ServiceError error = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), ServiceError.class);

String message = "Test"


    ValidationException exception = new ValidationException(error);

    throw exception;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return true;
    }
}
```

ValidationException extends ServiceException which extends RuntimeException.

Here is my @ControllerAdvice class

```
@ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
public ServiceError handleException(ServiceException exception) {
return exception.getError();
}
```

Error I receive says:

```
Exception thrown in handleError: {}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this compile? ValidationException exception = new ValidationException(,error);

Comment: I think you need `HttpServletRequest request` as param in your method:  `handleException(HttpServletRequest request, ServiceException exception)`

Comment: Sorry for , mistake. :)

Comment: @PauChorro you were almost right, I changed return type to ResponseEntity<ServiceError> and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to pass by param `HttpServletRequest request` and as @Laurynas suggest it should return `ResponseEntity<?>`. So the solution would be as next:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
    public ServiceError handleException(HttpServletRequest request, ServiceException exception) {
         return new ResponseEntity<ServiceError>(exception.getError());
    }
```